# How does the author concludes that the expected score is $k + 0,5$ between $(n,n)$ and $(n-k, n-k)$

Tags: probability, graph-theory

In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2689550.pdf?refreqid=excelsior:99396efc28b9abf70e2a973705ab5194), at page 302, the author calculates the expected score of a gamer who plays the game that a player guesses the colour of the next card, red of black, in a normal 52 deck, if it gets right, it scores 1, and not it gets 0.

The author defines a "game path" in n-n lattice such that one each vertex specifies the number of red/black card in the remaining deck. Then he argues that between $(n,n)$ and $(n-k, n-k)$, the expected score of the gamer is $k + 0,5$ provided that the contribution of the first card to the expected score is $0,5$.

But I couldn't understand how he did reasoned that the expected score is $k + 0,5$ between $(n,n)$ and $(n-k, n-k)$ provided that in this "interval" he always guesses the colour which is not the colour of the first card.

Any help is appreciated.

---

> A paradoxical aspect to counting cards in "Red or Black" is that the
>   expected score  grows proportionally with the number of times that
>   card counting gives no information. Those situations occur on the
>   diagonal: red = black. Suppose that we started at  $(n, n)$ and that
>   the first card in the deck is black. We can assume that this first
>   card  contributes $1/2$ to our expected score. Now suppose that our
>   game path meets the diagonal next at $(n - k,n - k)$. In the course of
>   traversing this path we would  continue to guess that the next card is
>   red since red $>$ black in that portion of the  path; therefore, we
>   will be correct exactly $k$ times and incorrect $k - 1 $ times during 
>   this part of the game. In the path from $(n, n)$ to $(n - k, n - k)$,
>   our expected score is  then $k + 0.5$ of a possible $2k$.

Comment: I see only page 301 ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please check again, it works in my browser.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen or you can try from https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689550?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=How&searchText=to&searchText=Beat&searchText=Your&searchText=Kids&searchText=at&searchText=Their&searchText=Own&searchText=Game&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3Ffc%3Doff%26amp%3Bwc%3Don%26amp%3Bacc%3Don%26amp%3BQuery%3DHow%2Bto%2BBeat%2BYour%2BKids%2Bat%2BTheir%2BOwn%2BGame%26amp%3Bgroup%3Dnone&refreqid=search%3Aa1e96418d1cc10bf666d08b4f35abe5f

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Also see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Seems that is almost exactly the same argument I came up with. - Re the website: should there be any control element anywhere that allows page navigation? It appears that I can only swicth to thumbnail overview and back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between two positions on the diagonal, one colour will continuoiusly be more likely than the other (namely the colour that is not the colour of the first card). So obviously, the best strategy to use suring that time is to always guess the more likely colour. On the way from $(n-1,n)$ or $(n-n-1)$ to $(n-k,n-k)$, this guess will be correct exactly $k$ times. Add the $\frac12$ from the first guess, and we have our $k+\frac12$.